# Ionic 3 / Angular 4 - Lazy load component from server

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I have angular 1 app and what i am doing there is to load controller+template+css files with [lazoLoad directive](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs) and its give me option to be very dynamically.
Now i convert my app to Angular 4 app with Ionic 3 how can i do this?
Load Component+template+css files to app?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need one for Angular 2/4, since it has built-in support for lazy loading.

Router component is the key here.

Have a look here -> https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/

Comment: its not what i am looking for.
I need to use it in Ionic 3 and my component files are saved in my DB.
What i am doing is to load the files with web service and when i get them on response i need to inject this component to my app

Comment: I'm personally concerned as to why components are being store in a DB. Can you elaborate as to how/why you're doing that?

Comment: @AvishaiPeretz I was about to ask the sane question as MichaelSolati. You shouldn't keep any of the injectable code in the DB. The approach is to create a frontend logic, and model that will eventually receive a JSON object from backend route. Now backend can be anything as long as you have CORS in place. You then parse the object, and use the corresponding data properties to bind to the object of the class.